# Insert into Select (Invalid identifier Error)

Tags: oracle

I have one Table called Andamio (the destiny table), with these columns:

```
CODTIPOLOCALIZACION
TXTNOMBRE
CODLOCALIZACION
CODCENTRO
CODPUBLICO
TXTDESCRIPCION
```

And another one called Centro (the origin one), with these columns:

```
CODCENTRO
CODPARKING
TXTPARKING
```

I want to fill all the rows with the same values in the first two columns:

```
CODTIPOLOCALIZACION = 2    for all
TXTNOMBRE = "Park"         for all
```

The third column comes from an Automatic Sequence:   'MySeq_seq'

```
CODLOCALIZACION = MySeq_seq.NEXTVAL
```

And the last three columns have to be the same from the origin table "Centro" but with the condition that there is no other row in the destiny table "Andamio" with the same values of CODCENTRO and CODPUBLICO equals to CODCENTRO and CODPARKING.

```
INSERT INTO ANDAMIO
        (CODTIPOLOCALIZACION, TXTNOMBRE, CODLOCALIZACION, CODCENTRO, CODPUBLICO, 
         TXT_DESCRIPCION)
SELECT '2', 'Park', MySeq_seq.NEXTVAL, Datos.CODCENTRO, Datos.CODPARKING, Datos.TXTPARKING
    FROM (SELECT CODCENTRO, CODPARKING, TXTPARKING FROM CENTRO centrop
    WHERE (centrop.CODCENTRO <> ANDAMIO.CODCENTRO
       AND centrop.CODPARKING <> ANDAMIO.CODPUBLICO)) Datos
```

I have tried these INSERT INTO sequence with many variations [using INSERT INTO table VALUES ('2', 'Park', SELECT(...))] and many others...
I always get the Invalid Identifier as Oracle claims there is no column called CODPUBLICO in table Andamio, but it exists indeed.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're referencing the andamio columns in the select part of the insert statement without also having referenced the andamio table in the from clause.

I suspect a not exists clause would give you what you're after, eg:

```
insert into andamio (codtipolocalizacion,
                     txtnombre,
                     codlocalizacion,
                     codcentro,
                     codpublico, 
                     txt_descripcion)
select '2', 
       'Park',
       myseq_seq.nextval,
       datos.codcentro,
       datos.codparking,
       datos.txtparking
from   (select codcentro, codparking, txtparking
        from   centro cen
        where  not exists (select null
                           from   andamio an
                           where  cen.codcentro = an.codcentro
                           and    cen.codparking = an.codpublico) datos;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! 
This is my first post, so I hope I didn't duplicate any question, as I didn't find any other like mine.

Comment: That's ok *{:-) You had plenty of information in your question (yay!) so it was easy to spot. FYI, if you're doing an `insert into ... select ...`, the select part is completely separate from the insert. You should be able to run it on its own, which is a useful way to check for errors etc.